# В каких задачах применяют html атрибуты

Tags: javascript

```
e.dataset

data-scr='22'
data-m='3'
```

Ок с этим понятно, но не понимаю в каких задачах к примеру понадобится такие атрибуты

`data-scr-m='22'`
`data-scr-n='5'`

В результате получим

```
{scrM:22, scrN:5}
```

Хочу понять, в каких задачах такой подход применим? Вот если бы получили к примеру

```
{scr:{m:22, n:5}}
```

В данном случаи это возможно бы и спасло, но не как не

```
{scrM:22, scrN:5}
```

То есть в чем разница. Почему бы сразу не писать атрибуты

`data-scrM='22'` `data-scrN='5'` вместо `data-scr-m='22'` `data-scr-n='5'`

Comment: например, потому что в html атрибуты регистронезависимы

Comment: html - это html, js - это js, это две разные плоскости и у каждого свои принятые соглашения написания данных.....изначально js вообще не существовало, только html......и там свои законы..........когда js появился, то не был нацелен на какие-то там дата атрибуты, которые появились несколько (20) лет спустя.... там (в js) были другие цели и свой синтаксис

Comment: Ну вообще, если нужно перечисление чего-то, то можно всё пихнуть в один аттрибут `data-scrs` со значением `JSON.stringify([22, 5])`. Ну вернее не именно это значение, а скорее результат этой команды положить в значение аттрибута